# Flex 4 Menu Error

Tags: apache-flex, menu, flex4

I have create a menu but when clicking on menu so that it shows, I get an error on the line because of the line "myMenu.show(null,null)". See function below:

```
private function createAndShowmyMenu():void {


                myMenu = Menu.createMenu(null, myMenuDataProvider, false);
                myMenu.labelField="@label"
                myMenu.setStyle("fontSize","10");
                                //Event Listeners Here


                myMenu.show(null,null);


            }
```

The Error is as such:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
    at mx.controls.menuClasses::MenuItemRenderer/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\menuClasses\MenuItemRenderer.as:469]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7933]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:863]
    at mx.controls::List/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::setupRendererFromData()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\List.as:1706]
    at mx.controls::Menu/measureWidthOfItems()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\Menu.as:1322]
    at mx.controls::List/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\List.as:906]
    at mx.controls::Menu/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\Menu.as:1244]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7933]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:863]
    at mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/addPopUp()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManagerImpl.as:384]
    at mx.managers::PopUpManager$/addPopUp()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManager.as:193]
    at mx.controls::Menu/show()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\Menu.as:1648]
```

Anyone has an idea with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myMenu = Menu.createMenu(SOME_DISPLAYOBJECT_HERE, myMenuDataProvider, false);
myMenu.labelField="@label"
myMenu.setStyle("fontSize","10");
myMenu.show();
```

You should really try to read the documentation, debug your code or even look at the sdk code before posting a question.

Comment: I did go thru the documentation, but you know my code works without specifying the displayObject when creating the menu in FLEX 3. However it didnt in Flex 4, and the doc did not say anywhere where the difference lies.

But thanks for the correction, it works like a charm.

Comment: The documentation says that the argument is non-optional (ie. not null).  I'm not sure why it didn't work in Flex 3, but if shouldn't of.